# Adding kendall tau to gtsummary

Tags: correlation, gtsummary

Iv created a table with gysummary using tbl_summary function.

The grouping is by tertiles: "Low tertile", "Medium tertile", "High tertile"

Using add_p, Kruskal Wallis test compares different characteristics across these 3 groups.

I wish to add a column of p-values from Kendall tau correlation (using 1,2,3 as numeric instead of "Low tertile", "Medium tertile", "High tertile".

Is this possible?

I tried calculating the correlations and saving the p values as a vector but couldn't manage to add it as a column.

Edited:
Here is the reprex:

```r
library(reprex)
#> Warning: package 'reprex' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(SciViews)
#> Warning: package 'SciViews' was built under R version 4.2.1
library(gtsummary)
#> Warning: package 'gtsummary' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> #Uighur


# Create sample data
n <- 10
data <- data.frame(
  VAT_Quantile_3 = factor(sample(c("Low tertile", "Medium tertile", "High tertile"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  Gender = factor(sample(c("Male", "Female"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  Age = c(50.1, 49.2, 48.8, 51.7, 52.6, 50.4, 49.9, 48.2, 51.1, 52.7))

tab_1<- data %>%
  select(VAT_Quantile_3, Gender , Age) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = VAT_Quantile_3,
              statistic = list(
                all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"),
              digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(1, 1),
                            all_categorical() ~ c(0,1)))  %>%
  add_p(,pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(., digits = 3))

#code for Kendell's tau:
cor.test(data$Age, as.numeric(data$VAT_Quantile_3), method = "kendall")
#> Warning in cor.test.default(data$Age, as.numeric(data$VAT_Quantile_3), method =
#> "kendall"): Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
#> 
#>  Kendall's rank correlation tau
#> 
#> data:  data$Age and as.numeric(data$VAT_Quantile_3)
#> z = -0.47891, p-value = 0.632
#> alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#>        tau 
#> -0.1297498
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (a reprex). Must include both data and code we can run on our machine. Please be sure to include the gtsummary code to produce your summary table, and code you're using to calculate Kendell's tau.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've now edited the post to include a reprex.

Comment: Thanks for updating Hadar. Apologies, but the example should be minimal, and only include essential lines to illustrate your example. This will make it easier for others to read and discover this solution in the future. Please update one more time.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel, Iv now edited the post with more minimal code.

Comment: Hi Daniel, is the minimal code I provided sufficient?
Thank you again
Hadar